# running command in bash script producing error

Tags: php, linux, bash

**problem**

Im trying to write a bash script that wraps `phpbrew switch` so that I can switch the apache module at the same time.   Everything is working, except that I can't get the `phpbrew switch php-7.0.01` to run properly.

**code** (`$version` being fed by input)

```
if [ -v version ]; then
        phpbrew switch php-$version
fi
```

**error**

> Invalid argument php-7.0.1

running `phpbrew switch php-7.0.1` executes with no errors.

Is there something odd going on with phpbrew? or am I trying to do something silly in bash?

**full script**

```
#!/bin/bash
# wraps phpbrew switch to enable apache switching

module_path=/usr/lib/apache2/modules
if [ $1 ]; then
        echo "switching php to version ${1}..."
        if [ $1 = "5.6.4" ]; then
                set=5
                version=5.6.4
                so_path=libphp5.6.4.so
        fi
        if [ $1 = "5.6.15" ]; then
                set=5
                version=5.6.15
                so_path=libphp5.6.15.so
        fi
        if [ $1 = "7.1" ]; then
                set=7
                version=7.0.1
                so_path=libphp7.1.0-dev.so
        fi
fi
echo "version selected = ${version}"

if [ -v version ]; then
        phpbrew switch php-$version

        echo "" > /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.load
        echo "" > /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.load
        echo "LoadModule php${set}_module $module_path/${so_path}" > /etc/apache2/mods-available/php${set}.load
        service apache2 restart
else
        echo "no version set"
fi
```

**entry into terminal**

> ./switchphp.sh 7.1

**full output**

```
switching php to version 7.1
version selected = 7.0.1 
Invalid argument php-7.0.1
```

**extra info**

$PATH output:

> /home/matt/.phpbrew/php/php-7.0.1/bin:/home/matt/.phpbrew/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: Please post something that can be reproduced, i.e., assign some value to `version` please (you could very well have some trailing spaces in `version`, which may not be immediately recognizable in error messages).

Comment: Could you maybe add the full script and an example of how you call it to produce that error?

Comment: updated. thanks for looking. its been driving me nuts

Comment: What does your full output look like?

Comment: How is the version variable populated? From a file that has `\r\n` line endings perhaps?

Comment: its run as in 'entry into terminal',  the version var is set in the if blocks.  it looks like the value is finding is way into the command call fine, as the confirms it. . there are no trailing chars in the error.

Comment: can you try php-${version}?

Comment: output $PATH in the script and be sure that the script has the php-$version binary's path included.

Comment: @b10n1k tried that with no joy.

Comment: @MattJoyce the binary is definitely there. Executing `phpbrew switch php-7.0.1` works perfectly

Comment: @miken32 full output updated.

Comment: DevDonkey I was concerned not about the binary but the env variable data.  If the $PATH isn't inherited between shells it won't know how to find the binary.

Comment: @MattJoyce ah thats an interesting point. Good thinking, Ill check that out. UPDATE: alas no joy. $PATH echos find out of the script itself.  Also, Ive noticed that phpbrew switch doesnt fail with an error if it cant find the binary.

Comment: Does `echo "phpbrew switch php-$version" | cat -v` show anything unexpected? This would show hidden characters, e.g. run `foo=$'bar\abaz'` and compare output of `echo $foo` and `echo $foo | cat -v`

Comment: @miken32 no all seems fine.  Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, so managed to get an answer on [github](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/issues/610#issuecomment-158888731)

all I needed to do was put

```
source $HOME/.phpbrew/bashrc
phpbrew switch php-${version}
```

before the command call in the bash file.  Clearly wasnt pulling the bashrc from my home dir while in the script.